# What is wrong with this code returning error

Tags: meta-tags

I am using this function to return metatag on front page of my drupal site

```
<?php
  if ($is_front) {  
    echo "<META NAME="KEYWORDS" CONTENT="Geek community,stuffs for geeks,geek contents,tech updates,electronics stuffs,tech geeks">";
    echo "<META NAME="DESCRIPTION" CONTENT="Get articles related to Drupal,wordpress,design tips,Electronics,Web designing,Linux and Programming.Join our Tech community where you can share and get answers for your queries.">";
  }
?>
```

But it throws the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /public_html/techiestuffs/modules/system/html.tpl.php on line 52

Anyone know what is wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 6):

PHP can define a string with `'` or `"`. Whichever one you choose, you can't have those characters in the string without escaping them: `echo "need to escape any \" in this string"`

You can use this instead to avoid PHP strings altogether:

```
<?php if ($is_front): ?>
<META NAME="KEYWORDS" CONTENT="Geek community,stuffs for geeks,geek contents,tech updates,electronics stuffs,tech geeks">
<META NAME="DESCRIPTION" CONTENT="Get articles related to Drupal,wordpress,design tips,Electronics,Web designing,Linux and Programming.Join our Tech community where you can share and get answers for your queries.">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused from the fact you are using the string delimiter inside the string itself. The syntax highlighter shows you that:

```
if ($is_front) {  
  echo "<meta name="keywords" content="Geek community,stuffs for geeks,geek contents,tech updates,electronics stuffs,tech geeks">";
  echo "<meta name="description" content="Get articles related to Drupal,wordpress,design tips,Electronics,Web designing,Linux and Programming.Join our Tech community where you can share and get answers for your queries.">";
}
```

It should be:

```
if ($is_front) {  
  echo '<meta name="keywords" content="Geek community,stuffs for geeks,geek contents,tech updates,electronics stuffs,tech geeks">';
  echo '<meta name="description" content="Get articles related to Drupal,wordpress,design tips,Electronics,Web designing,Linux and Programming.Join our Tech community where you can share and get answers for your queries.">';
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm but how to bring the meta description in next line.

Comment: Just append `"\n"` to the first string.

Answer (score 2):

Or even better, you can do this the 'drupal' way and place the logic into a module. Or better yet, use a module that someone else has written.

If you are using drupal 6 - [Nodewords: The Drupal 6 Meta Tags module](https://drupal.org/project/nodewords)
Or drupal 7 - [Meta tags](https://drupal.org/project/metatag)

This way if you ever change themes, the metatags will still remain.